# Flow through a packed bed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I'm given a situation where a horizontal tube is filled with metal oxide particles and a reducing gas is passed through it. I'm given all the parameters of the system, including the maximum pressure I'm able to generate across the bed and the gas flow rate I have. I'm asked to solve for maximum length that I can use and I'm given the standard equation for the friction factor in a packed bed (that uses change in pressure, perosity, etc.), the ernug equation and the Reynolds Number equation to use.

Since the pipe is horizontal I'm confused as to how the length limits anything. Could it be that they're looking for the maximum L before turbulent flow beings or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ergun equation gives pressure drop per unit length for a packed bed of particles. In your problem as I understand it, you have a maximum pressure that you can generate so look to equate these statements and solve for the pipe length.